# How to form a list of items inside the stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

From my database bellow:

```
CD_STORE| CD_PRODUCT | LAST_PURCHASE       |
4077    | 63920      | 2018-12-05 00:00:00 |
7003    | 64520      | 2019-03-13 17:55:40 |
7003    | 76008      | 2013-06-22 00:00:00 |
```

I want to do a query to return an output where for each store code, I have a product list containing the product code and the last purchase date:

```
[
    {
        "storeCode": 7003,
        "products": [
            { 
                "productCode": 64520,
                "lastPurchase": "2020-08-06"
            },
            {
                "productCode": 76008,
                "lastPurchase": "2018-12-21"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeCode": 4077,
        "products": [
            {
                "productCode": 63920,
                "lastPurchase": "2021-03-10"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Note that in json above, products from the same store (in this case storeCode 7003) are within the same object. But my code is producing different output, each product is being represented as a separate line instead of being grouped within the same store code the way I want:

```
[
    {
        "storeCode": 7003,
        "products": [
            { 
                "productCode": 64520,
                "lastPurchase": "2020-08-06"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeCode": 7003,
        "products": [
            {
                "productCode": 76008,
                "lastPurchase": "2018-12-21"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeCode": 4077,
        "products": [
            {
                "productCode": 63920,
                "lastPurchase": "2021-03-10"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Below is my code that produced the previous output. What is wrong? Why is this happening?

My classes:

```
public class StorePurchaseView  {

    private Integer storeCode;

    private Set<StorePurchaseItemsView> products;

}


public class StorePurchaseItemsView {

    private Long productCode;

    private LocalDate lastPurchase;
}
```

My converter:

```
public Set<StorePurchaseView> viewConvert(Collection<Tuple> list) {

        return list
                .stream()
                .map(tuple -> StorePurchaseView.builder()
                        .storeCode(ofNullable(tuple.get("CD_STORE")).isPresent()
                                ? Integer.parseInt(tuple.get("CD_STORE").toString())
                                : null)
                        .products(Set.of(StorePurchaseItemsView
                                .builder()
                                .productCode(ofNullable(tuple.get("CD_PRODUCT")).isPresent()
                                        ? Long.parseLong(tuple.get("CD_PRODUCT").toString())
                                        : null)
                                .lastPurchase(buildLastPurchase(tuple))
                                .build()))
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    }
```

**#Edit 1** -> Following code brings up a compilation error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Set<Object>> to Map<Integer,Set<StoreRepurchaseItemsView>>`

```
 Map<Integer, Set<StoreRepurchaseItemsView>> itemsViewMap = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> Integer.parseInt(item.get("CD_STORE").toString()),
                        Collectors.mapping(item -> Long.parseLong(item.get("CD_PRODUCT").toString()),
                                Collectors.toSet())));

        itemsViewMap.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> StoreRepurchaseView.builder()
                        .storeCode(e.getKey())
                        .products(e.getValue())
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Might I suggest you provide the sample source data in the list as it exists and also show the desired output after you're done.  Don't forget to include the appropriate classes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an attempt in the following direction:

1. As you stream your tuples, you need to use `Collectors.groupingBy` based on `tuple.get("CD_STORE")` as a classifier. That would set you up in the right direction for the expectation "products from the same store (in this case storeCode 7003) are within the same object". You would be possibly getting a `Map<Integer, List<Tuple>>` as a result of this.
2. Since the default implementation of grouping results into `toList` downstream with identity elements, as a next step, you would need to make sure you transform the values to `StorePurchaseItemsView` before collecting them. This could be solved by specifying a `Collectors.mapping` downstream such as `groupingBy(classifier, mapping(..., ...))`. Your transformation would here be based on `tuple.get("CD_PRODUCT")` logic and downstream to mapping would be `toSet`.
3. Following the above steps, you would have ended up creating a `Map<Integer, Set<StorePurchaseItemsView>> storePurchaseViewMap`, so as the final step you could transform each entry of this `Map` to your actual `StorePurchaseView` object and collect them into a `Collection` of your choice. This would follow the lines of:

   ```
    storePurchaseViewMap.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(e -> StorePurchaseView.builder()
                                                   .storeCode(e.getKey())
                                                   .products(e.getValue())
                                                   .build()
                         )
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or toCollection
   ```

I would leave the overall implementation to you, feel free to revisit with specific doubts with reproducible code to follow up.

Comment: thanks for the reply. at first i was stucked but I managed to evolve but I have a compilation problem. could you check my #Edit 1 please?

Comment: @NarutoTheKidUzumaki while `mapping` you need to use `StorePurchaseItemsView.builder...` rather than just `Long.parseLong...`